# How to hide js files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I have cordova-ionic project setup in Visual Studio.

Now I have ts and js files within a single folder. I would like to hide js files which has corresponding ts file in the folder.

How to achieve this?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, or version "15" (preview)?.  There is now a confusion difference.

Comment: @SteveKennedy Just edited Q: VS 2015

Comment: Dont include them in your project :)

Comment: @devqon Ha ha, then the app won't work!  :P

Comment: Wow!! I wonder why this question received negative rating! It is time Stackoverflow made it mandatory to mention reason for a negative vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on each file and select "Exclude From Project" they will be hidden, as long as you don't have "Show All Files" selected in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Ya, that can be done however, that is a lot of work! Don't you agree?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh that is also what I meant with my comment on your question. You should not include them by default, which is probably done by some extension like Web Essentials when you create a .ts file

Comment: @devqon When I create a ts file and save it, Visual Studio automatically generates a corresponding js file. Now I would like Visual Studio to suppress this js file automatically instead of excluding manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop VS from generating the JS files altogether by adding `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` in to the first `<PropertyGroup>` in your project (.csproj) file.

More information here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2326

This is probably not what you are looking for but it will achieve the outcome of not having .js files visible.