# Hiding generated js files in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

How would I be able to hide generated js files (Transpiled from Ts files) in the solution explorer?

Lets say I have an angular website. I add this angular project to Visual Studio (Chose Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise as my code editor). There seem to be no straight forward way to hide these generated js files. The solution suggested by [Hiding js files in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652738/how-to-hide-js-files-in-visual-studio-2015) looks very crude.

I am more into a solution similar to what has been suggested in 
[Hide .js.map files in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587949/hide-js-map-files-in-visual-studio-code) but it appears to be only applicable to VS code. How can I achieves this in Visual Studio? Where can I see the work space related settings for an existing web-site (angular project) added in visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Even through it is not exact answer to your question, I will recommend to not hide js files in particular editor, but organize project in the way, that compiled code located separate from source files. It is common to have `src` and `dist` folders inside your project. You can use `outDir` setting in `tsconfig.json` in order to achieve this.